# How to smooth scroll to each component of my page without using any anchor

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, smooth-scrolling

I want to implement smooth scrolling behaviouur on my html page, which is build of react components. Each component has a height of 100vh. I have seen many smooth scrolling tutorials and blogs which involves smooth scroll with the help of navbar tags or some anchor tags. I dont want to use any sort of anchor tag.
My question is how can I smooth scroll between components of my page using scrollbar. i.e if someone scrolls down, the page must smooth scroll to next component instead of hanging in between components and so on.

These are my components

```
render() {

    console.log(this.props);
    if(this.props.HomeHeroSec)
    {
        return (
          <div className={classes.containerclass}>
          
                    
            <HomeSec1 className={classes.section} herodata={this.props.HomeHeroSec} />
                   
            <HomeSec3 className={classes.section} cradata={this.props.HomeCrausal} />

            <AboutSec6 className={classes.section}/>
           
            <HomeSec4 className={classes.section} secData={this.props.HomeHeroSec} />
           
            <Footer />
                    
          </div>
        )
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

react-scroll package may help you to have a smooth scroll. https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-scroll